# Local PC Event Viewer not logging account creation/deletion

Tags: windows-event-log, user-accounts, audit, eventviewer, accounts

I have a GPO that is setting audit account management success/failure on a windows 7 workstation.

[RSOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkNtA.png)

[User Acc is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4Xc.png)

Any idea what could be causing this issue with logging events?

Comment: What is the value of the security option: `Audit: Force audit policy subcategory settings to override audit policy category settings.`

Comment: @GregAskew "Not Defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set this GPO setting:

Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Audit: Force audit policy subcategory settings.

Set this to Enabled.

Good!